# Are "What is [idea/object/thing]?" questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are "What is [idea/object/thing]?" questions off-topic?

Are they too simply because wiki describes them? it's still philosophy related because you focusing on philosophy's branch of metaphysics **What is it like**

Comment: Can you give an example question? Not all "what is..." questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I think this is in regards to the "What is a restaurant?" question...

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely okay to ask questions about what things are, insofar as they're framed in a way that's topical, reasonably scoped, answerable, etc. --One danger that these sorts of questions run, however, is that they might read somewhat vacuously if posed without a framework, theoretical context, etc.

So it might help to share a little about what you might be reading or studying that's made the question of "what a thing really is" important to you. Mostly this is about identifying/specifying the concern so that it can be meaningfully answered in the context of a few paragraphs.